# Do I have to pass my T in my abstract class to use it, can I use self / this

Tags: c#, generics

I have an abstract class on a bunch of data models for doing some database update / insert type work (Importing parts of complex structure -users and their settings- from one database to another).

It seems I can't use `this` to do any work with the items in T. I would have thought I could have done so. Instead it seems I need to make the method static and pass in an object of type T.

```
public abstract class AImportItemListDatabaseCalls<T, T2>
    where T : IImportListBase<T2>, IImportListDatabaseCalls<T2>
          where T2 : IImportItem
{


    public static bool ProcessListToDestination(T DataListModel, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction tran)
    {

        foreach (T2 item in DataListModel.ImportItems)
        {
            if (item.IsPaired) // Do, Do Not Insert work - different by T 
            {
                    if (!DataListModel.DestinationDoNotInsert(item, connection, tran))
                    {
                        //
                    }


            }
            else // Do, Insert work - different by T 
            {
                if (!DataListModel.DestinationInsertInto(item, connection, tran))
                {
                    //
                }
            }

        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Edit: what I would like to do

```
public abstract class AImportItemListDatabaseCalls<T, T2>
    where T : IImportListBase<T2>, IImportListDatabaseCalls<T2>
          where T2 : IImportItem
{


    public bool ProcessListToDestination( SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction tran)
    {

        foreach (T2 item in ImportItems)
        {
            if (item.IsPaired) // Do, Do Not Insert work - different by T 
            {
                    if (!DestinationDoNotInsert(item, connection, tran))
                    {
                        //
                    }


            }
            else // Do, Insert work - different by T 
            {
                if (!DestinationInsertInto(item, connection, tran))
                {
                    //
                }
            }

        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

solution:

```
public abstract class AImportItemListDatabaseCalls< T2> : IImportListBase<T2>, IImportListDatabaseCalls<T2>
          where T2 : IImportItem
{

 public abstract List<T2> ImportItems { get; set; }
 public abstract bool DestinationInsertInto(T2 item, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction tran);
 public abstract bool DestinationDoNotInsert(T2 item, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction tran);
    public bool ProcessListToDestination( SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction tran)
    {

        foreach (T2 item in ImportItems)
        {
            if (item.IsPaired) // Do, Do Not Insert work - different by T 
            {
                    if (!DestinationDoNotInsert(item, connection, tran))
                    {
                        //
                    }


            }
            else // Do, Insert work - different by T 
            {
                if (!DestinationInsertInto(item, connection, tran))
                {
                    //
                }
            }

        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: How "failed"?  Compiler error?  Runtime exception?  Other?

Comment: @phoog  the failed comment was just in the code example wasn't part of my question. My question is needing to pass T when clearly this abstract class will have that already, why can't have just use it?

Comment: But how do you want to "use" T?  If you want to use an *instance* of type T, then you have two options: (1) have type T derive from `AImportItemListDatabaseCalls<T, T2>`, in which case you can use `this` to refer to the current instance when calling a non-static method, or (2) obtain a reference to an instance of type T to the method (as a parameter or a result of a method call, for example), in which case the method can be static or not.

Comment: @phoog it's in the code example. I have class and method there for you to look at so right now I am passing T DataListModelto the method. I did this so I could use DataListModel.ImportItems - because I couldn't access just ImportItems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > It seems I can't use this. to do any work with the items in T

Of course, not.  What items in T?  `AImportItemListDatabaseCalls` does not *contain* a T or a T2.  It merely has those types (not object of those types) available to it.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
public abstract class AImportItemListDatabaseCalls<T2> :
                           ImportListBase<T2>, IImportListDatabaseCalls<T2>
                      where T2 : IImportItem
```

where there's now a base class based on T2.  THEN you can use `this.`

Comment: OMG thanks I think that is it I had just added the Abstract and wasn't thinking that direction. I'll look and get back to you.

Comment: No, that adds a whole layer of issues. my list of objects ImportItems is in IImportListBase<T2> so I need to create that in the abstract class, but then it says it needs an object reference. "An Object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'AImportItemListDatabaseCalls<T2>.ImportItems'"

Comment: I had to make a bunch of abstract property and methods for my Interfaces, and then remove the interface and throw overrides in my classes but... Yes that is what I should have done from the beginning.